# Availability of using 2 pole circuit breaker instead of 4 pole circuit breaker

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have a lot of 2 pole circuit breakers, can i use 2 of them instead of one 4 pole circuit breaker (3 phase AC)? And what will happen if one phase has a problem, will the 2 circuit breaker trip or only one?

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot. It's a requirement that if a breaker senses an overload or short circuit, that it open ALL poles, so multi-pole breakers are made with what is called a "common trip", meaning all poles open at the same time. By using 2 x 2-pole breakers, you could have a situation where only one of them trips, leaving the other energized. that is extremely dangerous.

And for those in North America who may be reading this, there are some systems elsewhere in the world where the Neutral must go through a breaker, hence a 4 pole breaker (we don't do that here).

Answer (score 1):

Not unless the manufacturer provides a kit for this.

The manufacturer will have incentive to do this because customers and distributors are eager to be able to carry fewer parts in stock.  **However, if the manufacturer does not do this, it is because it is impossible to do safely**.   Any solution would need to be certified by a recognized testing lab such as TUV, CSA or UL.

Lastly, compare what your manufacturer offers to the requirements of your local electrical codes. For instance in North American breakers it is impossible to achieve common-*trip* with a handle-tie; they can only provide common *maintenance shutoff*.  But then, NEC doesn't require common trip (only common maintenance shutoff) for multi-wire branch circuits or certain phase-phase loads.